# Do Control.SuspendLayout and Control.ResumeLayout keep count?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout

I can't quite think of how to phrase the question to be precise, but hopefully my meaning will be clear.  Do Control.SuspendLayout and Control.ResumeLayout keep count?

To put it another way, If I call SuspendLayout twice, and ResumeLayout once, is layout still suspended?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's little reason left to get stuck on a question like this.  The source code is available, titled "Reference Source".  The best way to get it is with the [.NET Mass Downloader](http://netmassdownloader.codeplex.com/).  Not every .NET assembly has its source code published, your backup is the venerable [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Anyhoo, the source code looks roughly like this:

```
private byte layoutSuspendCount;

public void SuspendLayout() {
  layoutSuspendCount++;
  if (layoutSuspendCount == 1) OnLayoutSuspended();
}

public void ResumeLayout() {
  ResumeLayout(true);
}

public void ResumeLayout(bool performLayout) {
  if (layoutSuspendCount > 0) {
    if (layoutSuspendCount == 1) OnLayoutResuming(performLayout);
    layoutSuspendCount--;
    if (layoutSuspendCount == 0 && performLayout) {
      PerformLayout();
    }
  }
} 

internal void PerformLayout(LayoutEventArgs args) {
  if (layoutSuspendCount > 0) {
    //...
    return;
  }
  //etc...
}
```

So the answer to your question is: Yes.

Answer (score -3):

> If I call SuspendLayout twice, and ResumeLayout once, is layout still suspended?

No. Layout is resumed.